# Spring data JPA OneToOne cascade

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I'm a bit confused by the effect of Cascade.ALL.

I have two classes:

```
class Task {
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "task", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private Status status;
}
class Status {
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "task_id", updatable = false)
  private Task task;

  @Column(name="name")
  private String name;
}
```

I thought saving status does not affect class Task since the cascade is applied to class Task, not Status, but it does modify the task object in my database.
So I'm wondering if

```
Task task = status.getTask();
task.setName(xxx);
taskDao.save(task);
```

has same effect as

```
taskDao.save(status.getTask.setName(xxx));
```

Is it different for
`statusDao.save(task.getStatus)` and `statusDao.save(status)` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your annotations confuse who owns the relationship. On the one hand, you are specifying the `@JoinColumn(name = "task_id")` making the Status entity the owner of the relationship, while on the other, you specify `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "task"...` on the Task entity, making it the owner of the relationship.

So status owns the relationship and when you save it, it goes over to task and finds that it also owns the relationship and has a CascadeType.ALL on it, so it applies the cascading on the save (PERSIST).

You should probably decide which entity should own the relationship and either remove the `mappedBy` or the `@JoinColumn`